# Connectors Development Dashboard not listing existing connectors, claiming "reached the limit"

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

We have created 5 or 6 Connectors last year, one of them is published to the Teams app store as part of a published MS Teams app. Now I have to make an update to some of the connectors. After login to the Connector Development Dashboard I arrive at the usual site (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Home/Login#!/publish) which is now empty: no connectors listed but an error message claiming that "You have reached the limit for the number of Connectors. Please remove some Connectors before adding more". With none of our existing connectors listed that advice is of course impossible to follow. See screenshot. Has anybody met this issue before? Grateful for any and all ideas, this issue has me stumped.

[Screenshot from the Connector Developer Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZNVy.png)

What I have tried:

- Logout and login to ensure I am using the same account that created the Connectors.
- Re-googled the online documentation for Office connectors and followed the link from there (in case it has changed) (it hasn't).
- Searched the internet and stack overflow for descriptions of this or similar problems.
- ...and now I'm here.

Comment: We are able to repro that issue , We have raised ICM for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: Thanks Sayali, looking forward to hearing about your resolution.

Comment: Now it's working fine. Could you please try it once:- https://outlook.office.com/connectors/publish                      [![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyXdl.png